# Conversion to arrow function inside foreach loop results in TypeError

Tags: javascript

I have this code block that I use to bind an event listener to every anchor tag with a `#` href. I decided to convert event listener's callback function to an arrow function but while the original code works, the modified one results in an error: `TypeError: undefined has no properties`. I have used arrow callback functions many times before and they do work fine. What makes it break in this instance?

Original code that works:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]').forEach((anchor) => {
  anchor.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.querySelector(this.getAttribute('href')).scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth',
    });
  });
});
```

Broken arrow callback function:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]').forEach((anchor) => {
  anchor.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.querySelector(this.getAttribute('href')).scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth',
    });
  });
});
```

Edit: I fixed the issue like this but I still cannot figure out how these two are different

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]').forEach((anchor) => {
  anchor.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    anchor.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth',
    });
  });
});
```

Or:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]').forEach((anchor) => {
  anchor.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth',
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Change `this.getAttribute` to `event.target.getAttribute`. Probably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because the use of `this` inside your function.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

> An arrow function expression is a syntactically compact alternative to
> a regular function expression, although **without its own bindings to**
> **the this, arguments, super, or new.target keywords**.

As @Ben Aston already mentioned in the comments you could change `this.getAttribute` to `event.target.getAttribute`

Comment: Ah, I did not know this. It seems I need to study this particular subject in depth. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad to help you. I know the struggle, javascript has a bunch of pitfalls like this.